# What's causing the tuple and get error in the django?

Tags: python, django

I am learning from the book Django3 by example. I am having a problem and I am unable to debug it. I am unable to understand what does this mean?

I am displaying list of posts on a page. This error happens when I click the particular post to view whole of the blog post.

Here is my error: -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/g/Programming/django/blog/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/g/Programming/django/blog/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 96, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/mnt/g/Programming/django/blog/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /blog/2022/1/19/what-is-model/
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.

    def post_lists(request):
        posts = Post.published.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', { 'posts': posts})
    
    def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug = post, status='published', publish__year=year, publish__month=month, publish__day=day)
        return(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post})
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')    

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published')
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])
    

    # managers
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: There is no trailing comma at the end of a `return` line in one of your views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in post_detail. You return a tuple instead of a rendered page

return(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post})

Comment: Thank you. It was silly of me.